# A bunch of tcp unseen segments and duplicates on wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, tcp, wireshark

Recently, my Mac has been unable to use the internet well. Even though it said my ping was between the ranges of 10-20 ms and my download speed was around 20 Mbps along with around a 10 Mbps upload speed (showing that the connectivity was at least decent), I was still unable to browse the internet. I've looked up nearly every solution I could, but couldn't find an answer as to why. No one else in my family has this problem.

I've already tried restarting my router, trying out different settings in my network preferences etc. In the end I tried using an Ethernet cable, and my download speed shot up to 170Mbps. This cured my problem, but when I checked my Wireshark capture, I see this.

[image: Wireshark image]

I'm a novice when it comes to networking, i.e. I know next to nothing. But seeing this many duplicates and keep-alives can't be good. What are the possible reasons for why this is happening? Is something wrong with the OS? Hardware? Or a virus/bot/spider?

I am not sure what could be causing this, so if anyone might have an idea, I would love to know. Hopefully, this isn't too big of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To rule out the router as a potential culprit, do you have other computers on the same WiFi subnet that you can run a speed test on to see if they have similar issues?  Also, do you have this issue on your mac with other wifi networks? (I'm assuming no, but need to rule it out as a possible cause)

One thing you can check is your IP configuration to make sure your settings are all correct - primarily that your gateway and DNS are setup right since that changes from wifi to wired sometimes depending on your router config.  If you have a dual band router, try limiting your mac to the 5ghz band to see if you see improvement on 802.11n/a/ac.

Also visit this website to analyze your tcp/ip configuration:

[speedguide.net tcp/ip analyzer](http://www.speedguide.net/analyzer.php)

It's tough to analyze a wifi problem remotely given the myriad of factors that come into play... but this will get you started hopefully.

[speedguide.net MAC tcp/ip optimization settings](http://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-can-i-tweak-macintosh-os-x-129)